# Strange behaviour showing by 2 frames(Tkinter) in the main window. How to fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I'm using Tkinter to make this GUI....The GUI was working fine in my pc but when i gave the code to my friend ....and when he run the code..The GUI was not looking the same as it was in my pc... 
Here is my friend's desktop
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eTG3.jpg
And this is my desktop
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4War.jpg
As you can see the frames are working different.....
How to fix it?

```
    #STATEWISE GRAPHICAL REPRESENTATION OF THE COVID-19 effected people

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser


root = Tk()
root.title("COVID-19 Alert!")
url = 'https://api.covid19india.org/data.json'
jsn = requests.get(url).json()
statewise = jsn['statewise']
df = pd.DataFrame(statewise)
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df['active'] = df['active'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
df['deaths'] = df['deaths'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
df['confirmed'] = df['confirmed'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
df['recovered'] = df['recovered'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
def graph():

    fig = px.treemap(df, path=['state', 'confirmed', 'active' , 'recovered'], values='active',
                      color='active', hover_data=['confirmed' , 'recovered'],
                      color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                      color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['confirmed'], weights=df['active']),
                      title = 'Statewise Cases',
                        )
    fig.show()

def bar_graph():
  states =df['state']
  fig = go.Figure(data=[
      go.Bar(name='confirmed', x=states, y=df['confirmed']),
      go.Bar(name='active', x=states, y=df['active']),
      go.Bar(name='recovered', x=states, y=df['recovered'])
  ])
  fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
  fig.show()

def Home():
    frame1.grid_forget()
    frame9 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#323232")
    frame9.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f9label1 = Label(frame9, text="\n\nStay Home, Stay Safe!\n\n", font=("Arial Bold", 15), bg="#323232", fg="#ff971d")
    f9label1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
    f9label2 = Label(frame9, text="", bg="#323232")
    f9label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    f9label3 = Label(frame9, text="", bg="#323232")
    f9label3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    f9label4 = Label(frame9, text="", bg="#323232")
    f9label4.grid(row=6, column=1)
    f9label5 = Label(frame9, text="", bg="#323232")
    f9label5.grid(row=8, column=1)
    f9label6 = Label(frame9, text="\n\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f9label6.grid(row=10, column=1)
    f9label7 = Label(frame9, text="\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f9label7.grid(row=12, column=1)
    f9label8 = Label(frame9, text="", bg="#323232")
    f9label8.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f9label9 = Label(frame9, text="", bg="#323232")
    f9label9.grid(row=0, column=4)
    f9button1 = Button(frame9, text="Home", command=Home, padx=54, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", state=DISABLED, activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f9button2 = Button(frame9, text="Symptoms", command=Symptoms, padx=39, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f9button3 = Button(frame9, text="Prevention", command=Prevention, padx=40, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f9button4 = Button(frame9, text="Treatments", command=Treatments, padx=38, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f9button5 = Button(frame9, text="Learn More on who.int", command=Learn, padx=5, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f9button6 = Button(frame9, text="Exit", command=root.quit, padx=61, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff5722", activeforeground="#ff5722", activebackground="#323232")
    f9button1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    f9button2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    f9button3.grid(row=5, column=2)
    f9button4.grid(row=7, column=2)
    f9button5.grid(row=9, column=2)
    f9button6.grid(row=11, column=2)
    frame2.grid_forget()
    frame10 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#fefdca")
    frame10.grid(row=0, column=1)
    f10label1 = Label(frame10, text="Statewise Graphical Representation\nOf\nThe COVID-19 Effected People", font=("Liberation Serif", 13), bg="#fefdca", fg="#f95959", anchor=CENTER, width=70, height=9)
    f10label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f10label2 = Label(frame10, text="***A Tree Map showing number of COVID-19 effected people***", font=("Liberation Serif", 11), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=70, height=6)
    f10label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    main_button1 = Button(frame10, text="Tree Map", padx=40, font=("Arial Black", 8), fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#fefdca", command=graph)
    main_button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
    f10label3 = Label(frame10, text="***A Bar Graph showing number of COVID-19 effected people***", font=("Liberation Serif", 11), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=70, height=6)
    f10label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    main_button2 = Button(frame10, text="Bar Graph", padx=40, font=("Arial Black", 8), fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#fefdca", command=bar_graph)
    main_button2.grid(row=4, column=0)
    f10label4 = Label(frame10, text="\n", bg="#fefdca")
    f10label4.grid(row=5, column=0)

def Symptoms():
    frame1.grid_forget()
    frame3 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#323232")
    frame3.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f3label1 = Label(frame3, text="\n\nStay Home, Stay Safe!\n\n", font=("Arial Bold", 15), bg="#323232", fg="#ff971d")
    f3label1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
    f3label2 = Label(frame3, text="", bg="#323232")
    f3label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    f3label3 = Label(frame3, text="", bg="#323232")
    f3label3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    f3label4 = Label(frame3, text="", bg="#323232")
    f3label4.grid(row=6, column=1)
    f3label5 = Label(frame3, text="", bg="#323232")
    f3label5.grid(row=8, column=1)
    f3label6 = Label(frame3, text="\n\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f3label6.grid(row=10, column=1)
    f3label7 = Label(frame3, text="\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f3label7.grid(row=12, column=1)
    f3label8 = Label(frame3, text="", bg="#323232")
    f3label8.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f3label9 = Label(frame3, text="", bg="#323232")
    f3label9.grid(row=0, column=4)
    f3button1 = Button(frame3, text="Home", command=Home, padx=54, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f3button2 = Button(frame3, text="Symptoms", command=Symptoms, padx=39, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", state=DISABLED, activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f3button3 = Button(frame3, text="Prevention", command=Prevention, padx=40, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f3button4 = Button(frame3, text="Treatments", command=Treatments, padx=38, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f3button5 = Button(frame3, text="Learn More on who.int", command=Learn, padx=5, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f3button6 = Button(frame3, text="Exit", command=root.quit, padx=61, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff5722", activeforeground="#ff5722", activebackground="#323232")
    f3button1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    f3button2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    f3button3.grid(row=5, column=2)
    f3button4.grid(row=7, column=2)
    f3button5.grid(row=9, column=2)
    f3button6.grid(row=11, column=2)
    frame2.grid_forget()
    frame4 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#fefdca")
    frame4.grid(row=0, column=1)
    f4label1 = Label(frame4, text="----SYMPTOMS----\n\nCommon symptoms:\ni) Fever.\nii) Tiredness.\niii) Dry cough.\n\nSome people may experience:\ni) Aches and pains.\nii) Nasal congestion.\niii) Runny nose.\niv) Sore throat.\nv) Diarrhoea.\n\nOn average it takes 5–6 days from when someone\nis infected with the virus for symptoms to show, however it can take up to 14 days.\n\nPeople with mild symptoms who are otherwise healthy should self-isolate.\nSeek medical attention if you have a fever, a cough, and difficulty breathing.\n\nCALL AHEAD.", font=("Arial Bold", 10), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=79, height=29)
    f4label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

def Prevention():
    frame1.grid_forget()
    frame5 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#323232")
    frame5.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f5label1 = Label(frame5, text="\n\nStay Home, Stay Safe!\n\n", font=("Arial Bold", 15), bg="#323232", fg="#ff971d")
    f5label1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
    f5label2 = Label(frame5, text="", bg="#323232")
    f5label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    f5label3 = Label(frame5, text="", bg="#323232")
    f5label3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    f5label4 = Label(frame5, text="", bg="#323232")
    f5label4.grid(row=6, column=1)
    f5label5 = Label(frame5, text="", bg="#323232")
    f5label5.grid(row=8, column=1)
    f5label6 = Label(frame5, text="\n\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f5label6.grid(row=10, column=1)
    f5label7 = Label(frame5, text="\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f5label7.grid(row=12, column=1)
    f5label8 = Label(frame5, text="", bg="#323232")
    f5label8.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f5label9 = Label(frame5, text="", bg="#323232")
    f5label9.grid(row=0, column=4)
    f5button1 = Button(frame5, text="Home", command=Home, padx=54, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f5button2 = Button(frame5, text="Symptoms", command=Symptoms, padx=39, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f5button3 = Button(frame5, text="Prevention", command=Prevention, padx=40, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", state=DISABLED, activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f5button4 = Button(frame5, text="Treatments", command=Treatments, padx=38, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f5button5 = Button(frame5, text="Learn More on who.int", command=Learn, padx=5, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f5button6 = Button(frame5, text="Exit", command=root.quit, padx=61, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff5722", activeforeground="#ff5722", activebackground="#323232")
    f5button1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    f5button2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    f5button3.grid(row=5, column=2)
    f5button4.grid(row=7, column=2)
    f5button5.grid(row=9, column=2)
    f5button6.grid(row=11, column=2)
    frame2.grid_forget()
    frame6 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#fefdca")
    frame6.grid(row=0, column=1)
    f6label1 = Label(frame6, text="----PREVENTION----\n\nSTAY HOME.\nSAVE LIVES.\n\nHelp stop coronavirus\n1) STAY home\n2) KEEP a safe distance\n3) WASH hands often\n4) COVER your cough\n5) SICK? Call the helpline", font=("Arial Bold", 10), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=79, height=29)
    f6label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

def Treatments():
    frame1.grid_forget()
    frame7 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#323232")
    frame7.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f7label1 = Label(frame7, text="\n\nStay Home, Stay Safe!\n\n", font=("Arial Bold", 15), bg="#323232", fg="#ff971d")
    f7label1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
    f7label2 = Label(frame7, text="", bg="#323232")
    f7label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    f7label3 = Label(frame7, text="", bg="#323232")
    f7label3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    f7label4 = Label(frame7, text="", bg="#323232")
    f7label4.grid(row=6, column=1)
    f7label5 = Label(frame7, text="", bg="#323232")
    f7label5.grid(row=8, column=1)
    f7label6 = Label(frame7, text="\n\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f7label6.grid(row=10, column=1)
    f7label7 = Label(frame7, text="\n\n", bg="#323232")
    f7label7.grid(row=12, column=1)
    f7label8 = Label(frame7, text="", bg="#323232")
    f7label8.grid(row=0, column=0)
    f7label9 = Label(frame7, text="", bg="#323232")
    f7label9.grid(row=0, column=4)
    f7button1 = Button(frame7, text="Home", command=Home, padx=54, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f7button2 = Button(frame7, text="Symptoms", command=Symptoms, padx=39, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f7button3 = Button(frame7, text="Prevention", command=Prevention, padx=40, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f7button4 = Button(frame7, text="Treatments", command=Treatments, padx=38, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", state=DISABLED, activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f7button5 = Button(frame7, text="Learn More on who.int", command=Learn, padx=5, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
    f7button6 = Button(frame7, text="Exit", command=root.quit, padx=61, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff5722", activeforeground="#ff5722", activebackground="#323232")
    f7button1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    f7button2.grid(row=3, column=2)
    f7button3.grid(row=5, column=2)
    f7button4.grid(row=7, column=2)
    f7button5.grid(row=9, column=2)
    f7button6.grid(row=11, column=2)
    frame2.grid_forget()
    frame8 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#fefdca")
    frame8.grid(row=0, column=1)
    f8label1 = Label(frame8, text="----TREATMENTS----\n\nTo date, there are no specific vaccines or medicines for COVID-19.\nTreatments are under investigation, and will be tested through clinical trials.\n\nSelf-care\n\nIf you feel sick you should rest, drink plenty of fluid, and eat nutritious food.\nStay in a separate room from other family members, and use a dedicated bathroom if possible.\nClean and disinfect frequently touched surfaces.\nEveryone should keep a healthy lifestyle at home.\nMaintain a healthy diet, sleep, stay active, and make social\ncontact with loved ones through the phone or internet.\nChildren need extra love and attention from adults during difficult times.\nKeep to regular routines and schedules as much as possible.\nIt is normal to feel sad, stressed, or confused during a crisis.\nTalking to people you trust, such as friends and family, can help.\nIf you feel overwhelmed, talk to a health worker or counsellor.\n", font=("Arial Bold", 10), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=79, height=29)
    f8label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

def Learn():
    webbrowser.open("https://www.who.int/", new=1)

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#323232")
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f1label1 = Label(frame1, text="\n\nStay Home, Stay Safe!\n\n", font=("Arial Bold", 15), bg="#323232", fg="#ff971d")
f1label1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3)
f1label2 = Label(frame1, text="", bg="#323232")
f1label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
f1label3 = Label(frame1, text="", bg="#323232")
f1label3.grid(row=4, column=1)
f1label4 = Label(frame1, text="", bg="#323232")
f1label4.grid(row=6, column=1)
f1label5 = Label(frame1, text="", bg="#323232")
f1label5.grid(row=8, column=1)
f1label6 = Label(frame1, text="\n\n\n", bg="#323232")
f1label6.grid(row=10, column=1)
f1label7 = Label(frame1, text="\n\n", bg="#323232")
f1label7.grid(row=12, column=1)
f1label8 = Label(frame1, text="", bg="#323232")
f1label8.grid(row=0, column=0)
f1label9 = Label(frame1, text="", bg="#323232")
f1label9.grid(row=0, column=4)
f1button1 = Button(frame1, text="Home", command=Home, padx=54, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", state=DISABLED, activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
f1button2 = Button(frame1, text="Symptoms", command=Symptoms, padx=39, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
f1button3 = Button(frame1, text="Prevention", command=Prevention, padx=40, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
f1button4 = Button(frame1, text="Treatments", command=Treatments, padx=38, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
f1button5 = Button(frame1, text="Learn More on who.int", command=Learn, padx=5, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#323232")
f1button6 = Button(frame1, text="Exit", command=root.quit, padx=61, pady=5, fg="#363636", bg="#ff5722", activeforeground="#ff5722", activebackground="#323232")
f1button1.grid(row=1, column=2)
f1button2.grid(row=3, column=2)
f1button3.grid(row=5, column=2)
f1button4.grid(row=7, column=2)
f1button5.grid(row=9, column=2)
f1button6.grid(row=11, column=2)
frame2 = LabelFrame(root, bg="#fefdca")
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
f2label1 = Label(frame2, text="Statewise Graphical Representation\nOf\nThe COVID-19 Effected People", font=("Liberation Serif", 13), bg="#fefdca", fg="#f95959", anchor=CENTER, width=70, height=9)
f2label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
f2label2 = Label(frame2, text="***A Tree Map showing number of COVID-19 effected people***", font=("Liberation Serif", 11), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=70, height=6)
f2label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
main_button1 = Button(frame2, text="Tree Map", padx=40, font=("Arial Black", 8), fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#fefdca", command=graph)
main_button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
f2label3 = Label(frame2, text="***A Bar Graph showing number of COVID-19 effected people***", font=("Liberation Serif", 11), bg="#fefdca", fg="#363636", anchor=CENTER, width=70, height=6)
f2label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
main_button2 = Button(frame2, text="Bar Graph", padx=40, font=("Arial Black", 8), fg="#363636", bg="#ff971d", activeforeground="#ff971d", activebackground="#fefdca", command=bar_graph)
main_button2.grid(row=4, column=0)
f2label4 = Label(frame2, text="\n", bg="#fefdca")
f2label4.grid(row=5, column=0)
root.configure(bg="#323232")
root.geometry("880x500")
root.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file='alert1.png'))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can't run your code as posted - it reference a bunch of functions that don't exist. Since the question is about the layout of the widgets, the functions are irrelevent. I recommend removing the `command` attributes from each button.

Comment: Most likely the problem is simply that you're forcing the window to be too small. Different systems have different default fonts and screen resolutions. I recommend removing the call to `root.geometry` and seeing how the program behaves on the other system. It's also best not to specify specific fonts since you don't know for certain that other systems will have the same font.